# How to properly capitalize a title in APA 7 style?

Tags: citation-style

Should you capitalize the word "a" following a colon? For example:

> Lipscomb, A. Y. (2021). Addressing trauma: a look at the college essay
> writing process. The Journal of College Admission, (249), 30–33.

Answer (score 2):

You should, yes. According to the APA [website](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/references/elements-list-entry#title) (emphasis added)

> **Format of the title**
>
> Follow these guidelines to format the title element. Additional guidelines for less common cases are provided in the Publication Manual.
>
> For works that are part of a greater whole (e.g., *journal articles*, edited book chapters), capitalize the title using [sentence case](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/capitalization/sentence-case). Do not italicize the title or use quotation marks around it.
>
> > Happy fish in little ponds: Testing a reference group model of achievement and emotion.

From the ["Sentence case" page](https://apastyle.apa.org/style-grammar-guidelines/capitalization/sentence-case) linked above (emphasis added):

> In sentence case, lowercase most words in a title or heading.
> Capitalize only the following words:
>
> - the first word of the title or heading
> - the first word of a subtitle
> - **the first word after a colon**, em dash, or end punctuation in a heading
> - nouns followed by numerals or letters
> - proper nouns (such as the names of racial or ethnic groups)